# Compressed framebuffer offloading

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I'm trying to write code that would offload framebuffer from one card to the other, and I'm wondering whether it's possible to efficiently use compression, since the memory seems to be bottlenecked in my case.

At the moment, I use simple readback & display routines:

readback:

```
glWaitsync(..);
glReadPixels(.., GL_BGRA, GL_UNISGNED_BYTE, NULL);
GLvoid *data = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_EXT, GL_READ_ONLY);
```

display:

```
glGenBuffers(2, pbos);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_EXT, pbos[curr_ctx ^ 1]);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_EXT, width*height*4, NULL,GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_EXT, pbos[curr_ctx]);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_EXT, width*height*4, NULL,GL_STREAM_DRAW);
...
glBufferSubData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_EXT, 0, width*height*4, data);
glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_EXT, pbos[cur_ctx ^= 1]);
...
glXSwapBuffers(...);
```

There is also some synchronization via mutexes and other miscellaneous code in there, but this is the main body of the current code.

Unfortunately, it seems that memory bandwidth is the biggest problem here (on display card side which is sort of a capable USB capture card).

Is there any way to optimize this via OpenGL compression (S3TC)?
Preferably, I would like to compress on render card, copy into RAM, and then send it downstream to capture (display) card.

I do believe that I've seen some people do this by copying framebuffer into texture, asking GL to compress it, but quite frankly I'm new to GL programming. So I thought I would ask here.

Comment: S3TC is pretty lossy (especially when you leave it up to the driver to do). While I think this is technically possible if you have support for automatic texture compression - you'd basically fetch the pixel data into a PBO, then upload it to a texture object and then read the compressed texture data back - the latency you're likely to incur from this would probably make it impractical.

Comment: What sort of framerate and display latency requirements are you dealing with? Another thought is simply to read a lower-resolution copy of the framebuffer back, then upscale it on the other card. Neither solution will give good image quality, but this one's simpler and faster.

Comment: Realtime capture of computer game in 1080p, main gpu is capable of pushing some 200fps, but capture card is bottlenecked by usb bridge (no idea how it works internally, some sort of pcie-usb emulation, linux recognizes it tho and is capable of displaying onto it).
Card exports rougly GL3.3 capability and handles compression and storage internally once I output into it, it also has it's own VGA output.

It has 128M VRAM and doesn't look completely underpowered, but USB troughput seems to be limiting it quite a bit.

Quite frankly, I'm just toying with it and learning in progress.

Comment: I don't think compressing it to S3TC would help clear the USB bottleneck unless you could send the encoded image directly to the USB capture device, which would require that the device supports S3TC (I kinda doubt it does).

Comment: It exports "GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_S3_s3tc" which would suggest it does.